# Non-constant Jacobian from transformation of a square

Tags: jacobian

Say I have a unit square in 2D that is defined by following matrix where each column denotes a point.

$A= \begin{bmatrix}   0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1    \end{bmatrix}$

Now I transform A with some Jacobian $J$:

$JA=B$

where:

$B=\begin{bmatrix}   0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 1    \end{bmatrix}$

My question is whether there is a solution where the deformation is distributed equally for $J$ - which I know can't be constant - and if so, how to determine it.

Comment: Each *column* denotes a point, or I am understanding nothing?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Each column it is.